# Сотрудничество двух функций через многопоточность

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Добрый день. Мне нужна Ваша помощь: у меня есть две функции - я
их чередую (многопоточность) мне нужно чтобы первая функция после окончания работы(у меня есть текст и я записываю его в очередь и когда уже не осталося слов сообщать) сообщала вторую функцию что уже закончила работу, а вторая функция это получала через многопоточность. Спасибо

Код:

```
   std::mutex mutex;
   std::queue<std::string> queue;
   std::condition_variable conditionVariable;

   void ProduceData()
   {
    const char* pathToFile = "D:\\text.txt";
    std::ifstream stream(pathToFile);
    if (!stream)
    {
    std::cout << "Can not open file\n";
    return;
    }

    const std::uint8_t maxWordCount = 5;
    std::string word;
    while (stream >> word)
    {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(mutex);
    for (std::uint8_t count = 0; (count < maxWordCount) || (count != '\0'); ++count)
        queue.push(word);
    conditionVariable.notify_one();
    }
   }

   void ConsumeData()
   {
     while (true)
     {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniqueLock(mutex);
    conditionVariable.wait(uniqueLock, [] {return !queue.empty(); });
    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        const std::string& str = queue.front();
        std::size_t numVowels = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isVowel);
        std::cout << str << "-" << numVowels;
        queue.pop();
    }
    uniqueLock.unlock();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Что у вас уже получилось? Добавте код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: mutex/conditional variable, producer-consumer

Comment: Используйте conditional_variable

Comment: @MrBin  а можете  навести пример использования  conditional_variable. Или линк где я могу увидеть пример использования

Comment: [Вот](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Comment: @MrBin   я сделал  как в  документации. Можете  посмотреть и сказать что нужно еще доделать?

Comment: @dimaslon, вроде нормально, не считая бесполезного `while(true)` (Вы делаете работу один раз, значит можно без него) + можно не закрывать `uniqueLock` вручную, при выходе из области видимости он освободит `mutex`.